# How to use string substitution in one command with command substitution?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, regular-expression, command-substitution

When the `git branch` command is executed it usually shows:

```
* main 
.... # other branches
```

Having the following through *command substitution* and *string substitution* work as expected:

```
current_branch=$(git branch | head -n1)     #1
current_branch="${current_branch/* /}"      #2  
echo "current_branch: '${current_branch}'"
```

prints only `main`

**Question**:

How to merge (if is possible) lines 1 and 2 in one?

```
current_branch=$(git branch | head -n1 | XXX)
```

What should be `XXX`?

Comment: 1) the `${var/pattern/replacement}` expansion doesn't take a regex, but a shell glob pattern. 2) does it matter if that's on two lines or one?

Comment: @ilkkachu updated the post - just for presentation purposes I created this post. So is not critical have all in 1 line.

Answer (score 1):

The `"${current_branch/* /}"`  expansion returns the value of `current_branch` with everything up to the last space removed. It's the same as `"${var##* }"`. If you want, you can do the same in `sed` (for each line, for input from stdin): `sed -e 's/.* //'`. Here, it might make sense to do that, since you already have a command substitution that sets the value of the variable, and you can add the `sed` to the pipeline.

Actually, you can use `sed` to replace `head` too:

```
current_branch=$(git branch | sed -e 's/.* //'  -e 1q)
```

On the other hand, you could do both with the shell's parameter expansions:

```
current_branch=$(git branch)
current_branch=${current_branch%%$'\n'*}    # remove from first NL
current_branch=${current_branch##* }        # remove to last SP
```

In zsh, you could cascade the expansions, e.g. with

```
current_branch=${"$(git branch | head -n1)"/* /}
```

but that doesn't work in Bash.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with parameter expansion. After all, parameter expansion works on *parameters*.

You won't always have "main" being the *first* branch shown. I'd suggest

```bsh
git branch | sed -n 's/^[*] //p'
```

However, there's another way to get the current branch (the branch of the HEAD commit) without having to process the output.

```bsh
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```